# Drag and drop gwt

Tags: java, gwt, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to delete a widget from a panel when I drop that widget outside the panel.
I looked up these tutorials and examples **http://code.google.com/p/gwt-dnd/wiki/GettingStarted** but I can't figure out how to set up the drop controller to drop it outside my panel.

Can you please give a hint or an idea?

Comment: Can you share some details on what you've tried and where you're stuck?

Answer (score 2):

If you instantiate a `PickupDragController` as

```
PickupDragController controller =
    new PickupDragController(pickupContainer, false);
```

and you drop your widgets outside the pickup container, then a `VetoDragException` is automatically thrown (as a result of that `false` in the contructor). See the JavaDoc or even the code in `BoundaryDropController` if interested).

You can then register a `DragHandler` and in its `onDragEnd` check if the exception occurred. If so, remove the widget. Something like:

```
class MyHandler implements DragHandler {
  // onPreviewDragStart, onDragStart, onPreviewDragEnd omitted.
  public void onDragEnd(DragEndEvent event) {
    if (event.getContext().vetoException != null) {
      // Not sure it works, but you get the idea.
      event.getContext().draggable.removeFromParent();
    }
  }
}

controller.addDragHandler(new MyHandler());
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the solution. Worked for me too. good research.

Comment: @Andrea Boscolo : i was not able to drag the last element out. When i debugged found its parent is null

Answer (score 0):

In the DropController (AbstractDropController) you have to define in the constructor, a element, where you can drop the elements.
Do you have some code snippets to help you concrete?

PS: I have build some D&D with this library you mentioned, in my opinion, it is buggy and not so easy to start with. But I didn't found a better native D&D lib for GWT, we tried to wrap the jquery D&D. It is very fast and smooth, but hard to wrap.

Comment: I know, that is what I've done. I've created a DropController extending AbstractDragController. What element do you propose to define in the constructor? I want to drop the widgets anywhere outside their panel.